# openlayers IE9 does not refresh

Tags: internet-explorer-9, openlayers

I'm having problems with an openlayers page using IE9, the map does not refresh properly after an update. The page works with firefox and chrome and produces no javascript errors.

On the page in question:

http://rabeca.org/?ip=buscar

entering the search string "xote" and clicking "buscar" should return 11
results and plot them as icons on the map. In IE9 (and perhaps other IE
versions) the icons are not plotted, even though the map is being
refreshed by the following function:

```
    function UpdateFeatureLayer() {
           layer.loaded = false;
           layer.setVisibility(true);
           layer.refresh({ force: true });
    }
```

In order to show the icons one has to drag the map with the mouse so
that Brazil goes first out, then back in to sight.

Any ideas please as to how this can be fixed?

Cheers,